# fotorama click trigger thumbnails from select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, fotorama

I used to fotorama plugin in my web site. My issue is when I select other product via selectbox, the thumbnails doesnt changes.

I need to add  data-serialid="xxx" on thumbnails.

Any suggestions are realy good.

Thank you very much.

```html
 <!-- jQuery, -->
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Fotorama -->
 <link  href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.5.2/fotorama.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.5.2/fotorama.js"></script>

<select>
<option>Thumb 1 Need Select</option>
<option>Thumb 2 Need Select</option>
<option>Thumb 3 Need Select</option>
<option>Thumb 4 Need Select</option>
</select>

<p>I need to change thumbnails with selectbox.</p>

<div class="fotorama"
     data-width="700"
     data-ratio="3/2"
     data-nav="thumbs"
     data-thumbheight="48">
 <a href="1-lo.jpg"><img src="http://s.fotorama.io/okonechnikov/1-thumb.jpg" width="144" height="96"></a>
 <a href="2-lo.jpg"><img src="http://s.fotorama.io/okonechnikov/2-thumb.jpg" width="144" height="96"></a>
  <a href="3-lo.jpg"><img src="http://s.fotorama.io/okonechnikov/3-thumb.jpg" width="144" height="96"></a>
 <a href="4-lo.jpg"><img src="http://s.fotorama.io/okonechnikov/4-thumb.jpg" width="144" height="96"></a>
 <a href="5-lo.jpg"><img src="http://s.fotorama.io/okonechnikov/5-thumb.jpg" width="144" height="96"></a>
 <a href="24-lo.jpg"><img src="http://s.fotorama.io/okonechnikov/24-thumb.jpg" width="144" height="214"></a>
  <a href="6-lo.jpg"><img src="http://s.fotorama.io/okonechnikov/6-thumb.jpg" width="144" height="96"></a>
 <a href="7-lo.jpg"><img src="http://s.fotorama.io/okonechnikov/7-thumb.jpg" width="144" height="96"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```js
var fotorama = $('.fotorama').fotorama(); 
changeThumb = function(obj){
  var fotoramaApi = fotorama.data('fotorama');
  fotoramaApi.show($(obj).val());
}
```

```html
 <!-- jQuery, -->
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Fotorama -->
 <link  href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.5.2/fotorama.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.5.2/fotorama.js"></script>

<select onchange="changeThumb(this)">
<option value="0">Thumb 1 Need Select</option>
<option value="1">Thumb 2 Need Select</option>
<option value="2">Thumb 3 Need Select</option>
<option value="3">Thumb 4 Need Select</option>
</select>

<p>I need to change thumbnails with selectbox.</p>

<div class="fotorama"
     data-width="700"
     data-ratio="3/2"
     data-nav="thumbs"
     data-thumbheight="48">
 <a href="1-lo.jpg"><img src="http://s.fotorama.io/okonechnikov/1-thumb.jpg" width="144" height="96"></a>
 <a href="2-lo.jpg"><img src="http://s.fotorama.io/okonechnikov/2-thumb.jpg" width="144" height="96"></a>
  <a href="3-lo.jpg"><img src="http://s.fotorama.io/okonechnikov/3-thumb.jpg" width="144" height="96"></a>
 <a href="4-lo.jpg"><img src="http://s.fotorama.io/okonechnikov/4-thumb.jpg" width="144" height="96"></a>
 <a href="5-lo.jpg"><img src="http://s.fotorama.io/okonechnikov/5-thumb.jpg" width="144" height="96"></a>
 <a href="24-lo.jpg"><img src="http://s.fotorama.io/okonechnikov/24-thumb.jpg" width="144" height="214"></a>
  <a href="6-lo.jpg"><img src="http://s.fotorama.io/okonechnikov/6-thumb.jpg" width="144" height="96"></a>
 <a href="7-lo.jpg"><img src="http://s.fotorama.io/okonechnikov/7-thumb.jpg" width="144" height="96"></a>
</div>
```

Available image change options in **Fotorama** are:

```
//Using index
fotorama.show(2);

// Next:
fotorama.show('>');

// Previous:
fotorama.show('<');

// Last:
fotorama.show('>>');

// Arbitrary id:
fotorama.show('some-id');
```

see [**Official Documentation**](http://fotorama.io/customize/api/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much. I need last one thing. How can add data attribute on images ? Be couse I need to change thumbs via data attributes. If it is posible.

Comment: If we are using any plugin, then we should use their available `methods` or `Api` options. `Fotorama` have only option to change thumb using index of the image

Comment: Thank you again. I accept your answer. Next step, I need to figure it out how to add data attribute on images for change thumbnails.

Comment: @atakanaydın welcome, updated my answer with available plugin option to change thumb image. Hope it helps! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found this whilst hunting for a Magento 2 solution.

Might be helpful for some:

```
jQuery("#product-options-wrapper .super-attribute-select").click(function() {
    jQuery('.fotorama').on('fotorama:ready', function (e, fotorama) {
        fotorama.show(0);
    }); 
});
```